# Problem using Dojo build tool, 'could not load' error now occuring when trying to use compiled scripts

Tags: javascript, dojo

I was following along to this post by Rebecca Murphey: 
http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/scaffolding-a-buildable-dojo-application

I was substituting her file structure with my own.

Running the normal version of the scripts works fine, but the moment I compile them using the build tool, the script errors.

It's very likely a small problem with how the files are referenced via my Profile.js script but maybe someone here can help me get the settings correct before running the build tool so the compiled files will work as they should.

My file structure is as follows...

/www
    /Assets
        /Scripts
            /Classes
                build.sh
                Init.js
                Load.js
                Profile.js
            /Dojo
                Dojo.js
    /dojo-sdk
    index.html

My index.html file has the following code...

`<script>

    var djConfig = {

        modulePaths : {

            'Integralist' : '../Classes'

        }

    };

</script>

<script src="Assets/Scripts/Dojo/Dojo.js"></script>

<script>

    dojo.require('Integralist.Init');

</script>`

...and the Init.js file has the following code...

`dojo.provide('Integralist.Init');

dojo.require('Integralist.Load');

dojo.declare('MyApp', null, {

    constructor: function(config) {

        this.version = config.version || '1.0';

        this.author = config.author || 'Unknown';

    }

});



var myapp = new MyApp({

    author: 'Mark McDonnell'

});



alert(myapp.author);

alert(myapp.version);`

...lastly, the Load.js file has nothing in it but this...

`dojo.provide('Integralist.Load');
alert('I\'m the Load.js file');`

...and this all runs fine. When I load index.html I get 3 alert messages, brilliant.

The problem occurs when I try to run the build tool.

Via Mac OSX i locate the /Classes/ directory and run 'sh build.sh' and the build.sh file within the /Classes/ directory consists of the following code...

`cd ../../../dojo-sdk/util/buildscripts


./build.sh profileFile=../../../Assets/Scripts/Classes/Profile.js releaseDir=../../../Assets/Scripts/Release`

...now, after running the build tool I have a new /Release/ directory created within my /Scripts/ directory, this /Release/ directory consists of...

/www
    /Assets
        /Scripts
            /Release
                /Integralist
                    /Classes
                        Init.js
                        Init.js.uncompressed.js
                    /dojo
                        --loads of dojo related files--

...I then created a separate index file called index-release-version.html and changed the script code as suggested by the article, so it looks like this...

`<script src="Assets/Scripts/Release/Integralist/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<script>

    dojo.require('Integralist.Init');

</script>`

...from here I get the following error...

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught Error: Could not load 'Integralist.Init'; last tried '../Integralist/Init.js'`

...and just for reference my Profile.js file that is used by the build tool consists of the following (and it's here I think the problem *may* be)...

`dependencies = {

    stripConsole : 'all',

    action : 'clean,release',

    optimize : 'shrinksafe',

    releaseName : 'Integralist',

    localeList : 'en-gb',`

layers: [
        {
            name: "../Classes/Init.js",
            resourceName : "Integralist.Init",
            dependencies: [
                "Integralist.Init"
            ]
        }
    ],

prefixes: [
        [ "Integralist", "../Classes" ]
    ]
}

Any help really appreciated as I desperately want to get my head around how Dojo works :-)

Thanks!

M.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have that djConfig variable in your `index-release-version.html`? It looks like Dojo is trying to find init.js at `../Integralist/Init.js`, but you somehow need to tell it to look in `../Classes/Init.js`

This is what your  modulePaths : `{'Integralist' : '../Classes'}` was doing in your `Index.html`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest working from the repo I linked to from my blog post (http://github.com/rmurphey/dojo-scaffold) -- I double-checked that it's definitely working :) -- and make changes to it until your changes break something, rather than trying to create your own structure right off the bat.

At a glance, I'm not 100% clear why you've got a Dojo.js file inside your directory structure, (is this the base Dojo lib or something else?), but the rest of Dojo is located elsewhere. If you use the structure I proposed, you can safely remove the djConfig declaration when using the built files, but as Dan mentioned, you may need to keep it if you're using a different configuration.